# Classes with dictionaries python

Tags: python-2.7, oop

I have two classes, defined as such:

class Facility:

```
def __init__(self,name,openingCost):
    self.name = name
    self.openingCost = openingCost
    self.connectionCosts = {}

def addConnection(self,cl,cost):
    self.connectionCosts[cl] = cost
```

class Client:

```
def __init__(self,name,demand):
    self.name = name
    self.demand = demand
    self.connectionCosts = {}

def addConnection(self,fac,cost):
    self.connectionCosts[fac] = cost

def isConnected(self,facName):
    temp = Facility(facName,-1)
    return temp in self.connectionCosts
```

The method isConnected is meant to check whether a Facility with the name 'facName' is in the dict connectionCosts or not

when I define:
f1 = Facility('ta',10), 
c1 = Client('some client',20), 
c1.addConnection(f1,3)

c1.addConnection returns False. What methods do I need to add to my Facility class to make sure it works? (Can't change the method isConnected, unfourtunatly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override **eq** and **hash** methods to compare class objects
Like:

```
class Facility:
 def __init__(self,name,openingCost):
    self.name = name
    self.openingCost = openingCost
    self.connectionCosts = {}

 def addConnection(self,cl,cost):
    self.connectionCosts[cl] = cost

 def __eq__(self, other):
    return str(self.name) == str(other.name.name)
 def __hash__(self):
    return hash(self.name)
```